# human to UNIX time conversion with PHP

Tags: php, unix, date, time

I have this strings like this: `Thu, 27 May 2010 07:00:00 GMT`

I want to convert them to UNIX timestamp

Is there any way?

Comment: Please, please, please try the PHP manual and Google before posting a question like this ...

Answer (score 2):

```
echo strtotime('Thu, 27 May 2010 07:00:00 GMT');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way! In fact, *there is more than one way to do it!* ;)

You can use strtotime();

```
$time_en = "Thu, 27 May 2010 07:00:00 GMT"
$time = strtotime($time_en);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php